# Copy multiple files from one directory to multiple other directories

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls, xargs, cp

I have a directory structure

```
Dir_1
Dir_2
Dir_3
Source
```

. The directory `Source` contains the files `File_1.txt` and `File_2.txt`.

I want to copy all the files from the directory `Source` to all the remaining directories, in this case `Dir_1`, `Dir_2` and `Dir_3`.

For this, I used

```
for i in $(ls -d */ | grep -v 'Source'); do echo $i | xargs -n 1 cp ./Source/*; done
```

. I, however, keep getting the message

```
cp: target ‘5’ is not a directory
```

It seems `cp` has problems with the directory names which have spaces in them. How do I resolve this (keeping the spaces in the directory names, obviously)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` you could do something like this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name Source -exec cp Source/*.txt {} \;
```

This command searches the current directory for all subdirectories one level deep, excluding `Source` and then copies the text files into each.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Oops! Good catch @Cyrus!